# Access .env variables inside the background.js under the react public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have created chrome extension application which has background and content js file under the public folder. The chrome extension application have build with react + web-pack.  I have to access the environment variables inside the background js. How would i access those env variables? I had explored a lot but couldn't success to get the better answer.